# How to increase Magento Fedex shipping rates for methods other than ground?

Tags: magento, fedex

We would like to start charging our customers an additional amount for any order that is not for Ground. (i.e. only for Overnight, 2day, International).
How can I manage it I have tried event observer with **sales_quote_collect_totals_before** event but it is not working for me please explan proper solution.

Comment: The important method is `collectRates`. check here http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/15/create-custom-shipping-methods-magento/

Comment: You can modify the rates in `collectRates` method

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/56055/2206

Comment: Ok I am trying this solution thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement this functionality, you have to override Fedex.php from /app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php.

To override Fedex.php.Just place Fedex.php file with same folder structure inside local folder.
/app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php.

To add extra shipping charge, update _prepareRateResponse() function.

inside foreach ....

```
foreach ($priceArr as $method=>$price){..
```

Update these code to

```
if($method != "FEDEX_GROUND")               
     $rate->setPrice($price*$extraPrice);           
else
     $rate->setPrice($price);
```

Thanks.Hope it helps.